# Using a while loop to take multiple user inputs via nextInt and keep on same line

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

new to the forum as well as being fairly new to Java so I would appreciate if everyone could bear with me here.  I have a simple project i'm working on for one of my last assignments and CANNOT for the life of me figure out how to get multiple integer inputs form a user, using a while loop to store in an array, entered onto the same line until the user exits.  Here's my code:

```
System.out.println ("Enter up to " + MAX + " positive intergers.");
System.out.print ("Enter -1 to quit: ");
int i = 0;
int z = 0;
while ((i < MAX) && (z != -1)){
         z = input.nextInt();
         if (z == -1)
               break;
         else{    
              array [i] = z;
                i++;
         }
```

I've found a number of options but none of them are things we've covered in class and I would like to use the info we've been given already. Is there a basic way in java to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** Here's what it's doing now:

```
Enter up to 10 positive intergers.
Enter -1 to quit: 4
5
10
4
-1
What number would you like to add to the array?
```

I would like the numbers entered to all appear on the same line with a space in between. PROF sample output:

```
Enter up to 10 positive integers. Enter -1 to quit: 98 46 23 72 15 52 -1 Which number would you like to add to the array? 999
```

Comment: What does it currently do and how does that differ from what you want it to do?

Comment: Also keep in mind that (most likely) no one here knows what you have covered in class and what not.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you provided and from your description it seems perfectly fine. My guess is that you are not able to exit from the input. When done giving inputs, press ctrl+D to exit

Comment: RIght, but I just wanted to try to get across that it is a basic java class is all, and most of the answers i've found seem to be outside of what i've studied so far. I'll edit my post to include what it it's doing and what I want

Comment: WHen entering numbers, just write them all and press enter once. You don't have to write one number and press enter, then write one more and then press enter again and so on... Got it?

Answer (score 0):

Good enough for me...I was confused with the sample output the prof gave me. I didn't realize I didn't have to hit enter each time...thank you for fast responses!